# How to load data from csv to mysql

Tags: csv, mysql

So the structure of the csv file is like this:

```
Country,City,AccentCity,Region,Population,Latitude, 
ad,aixas,Aixàs,06,,42.4833333,1.4666667
ad,aixirivali,Aixirivali,06,,42.4666667,1.5
ad,aixirivall,Aixirivall,06,,42.4666667,1.5
ad,aixirvall,Aixirvall,06,,42.4666667,1.5
```

The problem is that I don't know how to build the Load data query, I mean which separators to use and so on, mabe you guys can help me with an working example.

Comment: RTLM? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: I have read it allready but the query doesn't work, that's why I'm asking for an working example

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does that help you?

```
load data local infile 'myfile.csv' into table myTable fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
(Country,City,AccentCity,Region,Population,Latitude)
```

Comment: I have used an app called HeidiSql I changed the lines terminated by from r\n\ to \n